# Why there isn't "create server" button in pgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin-4

There in not "create - server" button in pgAdmin (postgres 14). There is only "create - server group". How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: create a server mean installing a new instance of postgres, pg admin can't do that
, you only can join them with `register` button
, or create a db on your existing server

Comment: The horribly named "create server" was recently renamed to "register", to actually reflect what it does.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is following an older tutorial and comes across this issue as I have. As mentioned by jjanes above, the option has been renamed to register.

[image: register server]